# Last value gets replaced inside array inside array

Tags: angular, for-loop

Hi I have two arrays as displayed below:

```
this.selectedEvntAccList.map(account => {
              account.options = this.viewItemData.corporateActionOptionDetails;
              account.options.map(obj => {
                obj.__hide__ = true;
                obj.accountNumber = account.accountNumber;
              });
            });
```

my first array object contains account Number. I want to append that account Number inside each option. But some how my last account's account number is the account number being replaced every time instead of the right one. Any idea guys?

Comment: produce a fiddle with sample json

Answer (score 1):

You are using map twice the first map function will be iterated but the second map function will get iterated for all the index of first map function - like if first array have 10 indexs and second have 10  - for every first index the second array will loop 10 times updating the account number

Best way is to go with for loop and updating the object based on the index - just change your second areay with for loop and map the object using index for both array `if(index === i) { then your code to update object }` where i is the index of second array

Otherwise you can write like this

```
this.selectedEvntAccList.map((account, index) => {
              account.options = this.viewItemData.corporateActionOptionDetails;
              account.options.map((obj, i) => {
                if(index === i) 
                {
                   obj.__hide__ = true;
                   obj.accountNumber = account.accountNumber;
                }
              });
            });
```

I hope this works - thanks happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that those values are arrays?
also you can do

```
array.push('new value');
```

to append value to the end of the array without changing any of the existing values.

or is it possible that this statement is reversed:

```
obj.accountNumber = account.accountNumber;
```